# Byte in x86 intel assembly padded with NOPs?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, memory-alignment

When working with single bytes, should 4 byte alignment be taken into account?

Intel x86 pseudocode. At the beginning of a 4096 byte page:

```
PAGEADDRESS:
    01
    NOP NOP NOP <- 3 NOPs necessary?
    cmp byte ptr [PAGEADDRESS], 01
    je ADDRESS
    ...
```

Comment: you need to think about to what alignment applies and to what it doesn't. Then your question answers itself.

Comment: The code is actually showing the alignment of the code after the data, which is a different kind of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cmp byte ptr [PAGEADDRESS], 01` instruction just deals with the one byte at *PAGEADDRESS*. It doesn't matter what the subsequent bytes are filled with. The fact that these are NOPs does not impact the `cmp` instruction.

- Dwords in memory should start at 4-byte aligned addresses.
- Words are only mis-aligned when they cross such a 4-byte aligned border.
- Bytes can never be mis-aligned.

Comment: Where are you getting the 4-byte boundary for words from?  Is that from the atomicity guarantees for P5?

Comment: The Assembly/Compiler coding rule 46 (Intel optimization manual) says: "Align 16-bit data to be contained within an aligned 4-byte word."

Comment: Then in the next paragraph they say that you should just avoid crossing 16-byte boundaries.  (Which makes sense for Sandybridge/Ivybridge which use a banked L1D cache).  This optimization advice is totally uarch-dependent.  It's not wrong or bad, just maybe overly specific or restrictive.  Always remember when reading Intel's optimization manual that it has evolved over a long period, and a significant amount of stuff in it is specific to P4, and not relevant for P6 / SnB-family.

Comment: @PeterCordes Are you referring to "As long as 16-byte boundaries (and cache lines) are
never crossed, natural alignment is not strictly necessary" ?

Comment: Yes.  On Haswell and later, I think only 64B boundaries matter at all.  (At least for cached accesses.  For uncached word loads/stores, 4B might still be relevant.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Would you agree that for the non-optimization-experts amongst us, the old creed is still *easiest* to follow?

Comment: I think if I had to recommend something to remember, I'd say "don't cross 8B boundaries", because I think Bulldozer-family cares about that (at least for atomicity).  And that is more than enough on Intel.  But yes, I know it's useful to simplify things down to a rule that you can always follow, even if it means wasting some cache footprint on padding sometimes.  I'd say naturally-align everything whenever possible, because that's always good.  (And 16B-align the start of arrays so you you can vectorize without cache-line splits).